# Update a column of NAs in one data table with the value from a column in another data table

Tags: r, reference, data.table

I have seen a similar post on this topic, but could not comprehend the solution. Essentially I have a data table (DT1) with scores and some NAs. Wherever there is an 'NA' I would like a process that references another data (DT2) table that has a common column in both tables (tract) and then update the NA in DT1 with the value of DT2's score column.  I am choosing a data table class because I think it is a an efficient option.

DT1

```
         tract CreditScore    
1: 36107020401         635  
2: 36083052403          NA  
3: 36091062602          NA  
4: 36067013000          NA  
5: 36083052304          NA
```

DT2

```
         tract CreditScore  
1: 36107020401         635  
2: 36083052403         650  
3: 36091062602         335  
4: 36067013000         777  
5: 36083052304         663
```

Comment: If you're using the `data.table` package, you need to make this clear in your question. It's unclear to me if you mean a data structure specific to `data.table` or the base structure `data.frame`. Is there a reason (such as size / memory concerns) you can't just merge the two tables and use `ifelse()` to create a new column which has the appropriate value?

Comment: @Alex, yes there is. He could as well just load the data into Excel and a do a `vlookup`, don't he? More specifically, `data.table` can perform a *binary* join and update columns *by reference while joining*. This would be more efficient than `merge` + `ifelse` by several factors on a big data set.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes, the main reason for me choosing to use the data.table package is its overall efficiency. I didn't want to add another column to DT1 if I didn't need to. I will try the answer below and see how it works.....thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We've created new (and more comprehensive) [HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for some of the data.table concepts. Have a look [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944) for the other vignettes that we are working on. I'm working on vignettes for joins, which when done will hopefully clarify these type of problems better.

---

The idea is to first `setkey()` on `DT1` on the column `tract`.

```
setkey(DT1, tract)
```

In data.tables, a join of the form `x[i]` requires key for `x`, but not necessarily for `i`. This results in two scenarios:

- If `i` also has key set -- the first key column of `i` is matched against first key column of `x`, second against second and so on..
- If `i` doesn't have key set -- the first column of `i` is matched against the first *key* column of `x`, second column of `i` against second *key* column of `x` and so on..

In this case, since your first column in `i` is also `tract`, we'll skip setting key on `i`.

Then, we perform a join of the form `x[i]`. By doing this, for each `i` the matching row indices in `x` is computed, and then the join result is materialised. However, we don't want the entire join result as a new data.table. Rather, we want to update `DT1`'s `CreditScore` column with `DT2`'s on those matching rows..

In data.tables, we can perform that operation while joining, by providing the expression in `j`, as follows:

```
DT1[DT2, CreditScore := i.CreditScore]
#          tract CreditScore
# 1: 36067013000         777
# 2: 36083052304         663
# 3: 36083052403         650
# 4: 36091062602         335
# 5: 36107020401         635
```

`DT1[DT2` part finds the matching rows in `DT1` for each row in `DT2`. And if there's a match, we want `DT2`'s value to be updated in `DT1`. We accomplish that by using `i.CreditScore` -- it refers to `DT2`'s `CreditScore` column (`i.` is a prefix used to distinguish columns with identical names between `x` and `i` data.tables).

---

**Update:** As pointed out under comments, the solution above would also update the non-NA values in `DT1`. Therefore the way to do it would be:

```
DT1[is.na(CreditScore), CreditScore := DT2[.(.SD), CreditScore]]
```

On those rows where `CreditScore` from `DT1` is `NA`, replace `CreditScore` from `DT1` with the values from `CreditScore` obtained from the join of `DT2[.(.SD)]`, where `.SD` corresponds to the subset of data.table that contains all the rows where `CreditScore` is `NA`.

HTH

Comment: Am I right that this uses `CreditScore` from `DT2` for every matching `tract`? As I understand the OP, the `DT2`value should only be taken if it is `NA` in `DT1`. In the example given, it does not matter since it is 635 in both tables for the common record. If they were different, how could the `DT1` value be retained?

Comment: I'm being told `.SD` is locked when trying to implement this solution.

Comment: @MichaelChirico yeah, I'm seeing the same behavior and can't understand when it is locked and when it isn't. For instance, it is isn't locked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29659895/3001626) but it is locked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910869/join-on-multiple-keys-and-conditional-update#comment65183841_38910869). Dunno...

Comment: @DavidArenburg hmm, smells like a bug to me

Comment: I believe that means you just need to set the key in `DT2` also

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` alternative is `rows_patch`:

```r
library(dplyr)
rows_patch(DT1, DT2)
```