# Conditional binary join and update by reference using the data.table package

Tags: r, join, data.table

So here is my real life problem which I feel like can be easily solved and I'm missing something obvious here. I have two big data sets called `TK` and `DFT`

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
(TK <- data.table(venue_id = rep(1:3, each = 2), 
                  DFT_id = rep(1:3, 2), 
                  New_id = sample(1e4, 6),
                  key = "DFT_id"))

#    venue_id DFT_id New_id
# 1:        1      1   2876
# 2:        1      2   7883
# 3:        2      3   4089
# 4:        2      1   8828
# 5:        3      2   9401
# 6:        3      3    456

(DFT <- data.table(venue_id = rep(1:2, each = 2), 
                   DFT_id = 1:4, 
                   New_id = sample(4),
                   key = "DFT_id"))

#    venue_id DFT_id New_id
# 1:        1      1      3
# 2:        1      2      4
# 3:        2      3      2
# 4:        2      4      1
```

I want to perform a **binary left join** to `TK` on the `DFT_id` column when `venue_id %in% 1:2`, while updating `New_id` **by reference**. In other words, the desired result would be

```
TK
#    venue_id DFT_id New_id
# 1:        1      1      3
# 2:        2      1      3
# 3:        1      2      4
# 4:        3      2   9401
# 5:        2      3      2
# 6:        3      3    456
```

I was thinking to combine both conditions, but it didn't work (still not sure why)

```
TK[venue_id %in% 1:2 & DFT, New_id := i.New_id][]
# Error in `[.data.table`(TK, DFT & venue_id %in% 1:2, `:=`(New_id, i.New_id)) : 
#   i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). 
# Please let datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #1611.
```

My next idea was to use chaining which partially achieves the goal by joining correctly but on some temporary table without actually affecting `TK`

```
TK[venue_id %in% 1:2][DFT, New_id := i.New_id][]
TK
#    venue_id DFT_id New_id
# 1:        1      1   2876
# 2:        2      1   8828
# 3:        1      2   7883
# 4:        3      2   9401
# 5:        2      3   4089
# 6:        3      3    456
```

So to make clear, I'm well aware that I can split `TK` into two tables, perform the join and then `rbind` again, but I'm doing many different conditional joins like this and I'm also looking for both speed and memory efficient solutions.

This also means that I am *not* looking for a `dplyr` solution as I'm trying to use both *binary join* and the *update by reference* features which only exist in the `data.table` package IIRC.

---

For additional information see these vignettes:

- [Update by reference](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html)
- [Binary joins](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copying from Arun's updated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889057/update-a-column-of-nas-in-one-data-table-with-the-value-from-a-column-in-another)

```
TK[venue_id %in% 1:2, New_id := DFT[.SD, New_id]][]
#    venue_id DFT_id New_id
# 1:        1      1      3
# 2:        2      1      3
# 3:        1      2      4
# 4:        3      2   9401
# 5:        2      3      2
# 6:        3      3    456
```

His answer gives the details of what is going on.

Comment: @Arun could you ellaborate on your comment on the other answer for how this can be used to update several columns? I can't seem to parse out how it can be done cleanly--using `.SDcols`, e.g. For now, I'm using `:=` and naming each explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a very simple approach:

```
TK[DFT, New_id := fifelse(venue_id %in% 1:2, i.New_id, New_id)][]
#    venue_id DFT_id New_id
# 1:        1      1      3
# 2:        2      1      3
# 3:        1      2      4
# 4:        3      2   9401
# 5:        2      3      2
# 6:        3      3    456
```

I haven't checked, but I suspect the other answer is faster.

Comment: When you've to update more than one column as well, the other one is nicer.. I find.

Comment: @Arun I agree. Although tbh neither solution is particularly aesthetically pleasing to me, I almost want OP's original attempt to work, except that it makes no sense.

Comment: Smth like this would be more palatable for me if it worked: `TK[venue_id %in% 1:2, .SD[DFT, New_id := i.New_id]]`

Comment: it's not *that* bad ;-), but I agree it would be nice. although I'm not sure if it's possible (or how) with the current design..

Comment: Why my approach makes "*no sense*"? It makes perfect sense to me. `i` expression is trying to evaluate `DFT` and when not found, performs a binary join on `DFT` in the global environment (pretty much what happens in a regular binary join I believe) and the same process happens with `venue_id`, though `venue_id` is found in the parent environment and is being evaluated there. Evaluating from different environments is something acceptable within the `data.table` environment, for example `vec <- 3 ; DT <- data.table(A = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), B = 1:4) ; DT[B %in% vec & A == "b"]`

Comment: I get an error with this, unless I add `allow.cartesian=TRUE`. Perhaps because I'm using version 1.9.4?

Comment: @DaveTurek, yes. It is a recent change allowing duplicated Id's.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I really want it to make sense, but if that worked it would completely violate regular R syntax - how is one to know that your "&" there is a new magical kind of an *and* operator, instead of the regular one, that would literally apply the operation between the vector and the `data.table`? You could though introduce a new operator, call it let's say `%and%`, and then it would make perfect sense.

Comment: I can confirm (anecdotally, no benchmarking) the other answer wins on speed, _especially_ if you've to update more than one column conditionally