# Update a data.table based on another data table

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I want to update the columns in an old `data.table` based on a new `data.table` only when the value is not NA.

```
DT_old = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c")), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:3, l=c(1,1,1))
DT_old
   x y v l
1: a 1 1 1
2: b 3 2 1
3: c 6 3 1
DT_new = data.table(x=rep(c("b","c",'d')), y=c(9,6,10), v=c(2,NA,10), z=c(9,9,9))
DT_new
   x  y  v z
1: b  9  2 9
2: c  6  NA 9
3: d 10 10 9
```

I want the output to be

```
   x  y  v z
1: b  9  2 9
2: c  6  3 9
3: d 10 10 9
4: a 1 1 NA
```

Currently I am merging the two `data.table` and going through each column and replacing the NA in the new data.table

```
DT_merged <- merge(DT_new, DT_old, all=TRUE, by='x')
DT_merged
   x y.x v.x  z y.y v.y  l
1: a  NA  NA NA   1   1  1
2: b   9   2  9   3   2  1
3: c   6  NA  9   6   3  1
4: d  10  10  9  NA  NA NA
DT_merged[is.na(y.x), y.x := y.y]
DT_merged[is.na(v.x), v.x := v.y]
DT_merged = DT_merged[, list(y=y.x, v=v.x, z=z)
```

Is there a better way to do the above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this. First, I will expand `DT_new` according to the unique values combination of `x` columns of both tables using binary join

```
res <- setkey(DT_new, x)[unique(c(x, DT_old$x))]
res
#    x  y  v  z
# 1: b  9  2  9
# 2: c  6 NA  9
# 3: d 10 10  9
# 4: a NA NA NA
```

Then, I will updated the two columns in `res` by reference using another binary join

```
setkey(res, x)[DT_old, `:=`(y = i.y, v = i.v)]
res
#    x  y  v  z
# 1: a  1  1 NA
# 2: b  3  2  9
# 3: c  6  3  9
# 4: d 10 10  9
```

---

Following the comments section, it seems that you are trying to join *each* column by its own condition. There is no simple way of doing such thing in R or any language AFAIK. Thus, your own solution could be a good option by itself.

Though, here are some other alternatives, mainly taken from [a similar question I myself asked not long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658627/conditional-binary-join-and-update-by-reference-using-the-data-table-package)

Using two `ifelse` statments

```
setkey(res, x)[DT_old, `:=`(y = ifelse(is.na(y), i.y, y), 
                            v = ifelse(is.na(v), i.v, v))]
```

Two separate conditional joins

```
setkey(res, x) ; setkey(DT_old, x) ## old data set needs to be keyed too now
res[is.na(y), y := DT_old[.SD, y]]
res[is.na(v), v := DT_old[.SD, v]]
```

Both will give you what you need.

---

**P.S.**

If you don't want warnings, you need to define the corresponding column classes correctly, e.g. `v` column in `DT_new` should be defined as `v= c(2L, NA_integer_, 10L)`

Comment: Many thanks. Can you briefly explain how does `:=`(y = i.y, v = i.v) work?

Comment: It means: assign a certain column from the old data to the new only on the rows you were able to join on. The `i.` distinguish between columms with the same name in both data sets.

Comment: But this update all the values from DT_old. My expected output for the second row is `b 9 2 9`.