# Filling NA values in a panel data

Tags: r, merge, aggregate

I have a panel data containing NA values. I would like to fill in the NAs by the values of an other data. Let say I want to complete the following `panel` with `new.df`.

```
panel <- data.frame("time" = c(rep(2000,5), rep(2001,5)), 
                    "var1" = rep(1:5, times=2), 
                    "var2" = c(NA,'b','c',NA,'d','a1','b1','c1',NA,'d1'))

new.df <- data.frame("time" = c(2000:2001), 
                     "var1" = c(4,4), 
                     "var2" = c('e','e'))
```

I tried different combination of merge / aggregate / ddplyr etc.. The issue is that `merge` or `merge.data.frame` creates additional columns indexed by `.x` and `.y` even tho the colnames are identical.

```
> merge(panel,new.df,by = c("time","var1"), all=T)
   time var1 var2.x var2.y
1  2000    1   <NA>   <NA>
2  2000    2      b   <NA>
3  2000    3      c   <NA>
4  2000    4   <NA>      e
5  2000    5      d   <NA>
6  2001    1     a1   <NA>
7  2001    2     b1   <NA>
8  2001    3     c1   <NA>
9  2001    4   <NA>      e
10 2001    5     d1   <NA>
```

I tried also to play with the `na.action` option without success because the panel will still be incomplete after merging and the remaining `NA`must stay as they are. (Depending on the formulation, NA treatment will in some cases replace `NA` by `0`, or by `NaN`)

I would like to find a way to target the correct indexes in the panel to "insert" `new.df$var2` at its right place, knowing that I have a very large panel and it will remain incomplete at the end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you creating those data sets using `cbind` rather a `data.frame`? Is that on purpose?

Comment: I would suggest you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41440339/3001626) answer out as it will allow you to update as many columns you like at once. Some thing like `cols <- setdiff(colnames(new.df), c("time", "var1")) ; library(data.table) ; setDT(panel)[setDT(new.df), (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols)), on = c("time", "var1")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `coalesce` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
full_join(as.data.frame(panel),as.data.frame(new.df),by = c("time","var1")) %>% 
       mutate_each(funs(as.character), var2.x:var2.y) %>%
       mutate(var2= coalesce(var2.x, var2.y)) %>% 
       select(-var2.x, -var2.y)
#   time var1 var2
#1  2000    1 <NA>
#2  2000    2    b
#3  2000    3    c
#4  2000    4    e
#5  2000    5    d
#6  2001    1   a1
#7  2001    2   b1
#8  2001    3   c1
#9  2001    4    e
#10 2001    5   d1
```

---

Or we can use a `base R` option with `max.col`.  Here, 'd1' is the OP's output with `merge`

```
 d1$var2 <-d1[,3:4][cbind(1:nrow(d1), max.col(!is.na(d1[3:4]), "first"))]
 d1$var
 #[1] NA   "b"  "c"  "e"  "d"  "a1" "b1" "c1" "e"  "d1"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Recreate data as data frame

```
library(dplyr)
panel <- data_frame("time" = c(rep(2000,5), rep(2001,5)), 
                    "var1" = rep(1:5, times=2), 
                    "var2" = c(NA,'b','c',NA,'d','a1','b1','c1',NA,'d1'))

new.df <- data_frame("time" = c(2000:2001), 
                     "var1" = c(4,4), 
                     "var2" = c('e','e'))
```

## Solution 1 Fill NA values with base R merge

```
panelnew <- merge(panel,new.df,by = c("time","var1"), all=T)
panelnew$var2 <- ifelse(is.na(panelnew$var2.x), panelnew$var2.y, panelnew$var2.x)
panelnew[c("time","var1","var2")]
   time var1 var2
1  2000    1 <NA>
2  2000    2    b
3  2000    3    c
4  2000    4    e
5  2000    5    d
6  2001    1   a1
7  2001    2   b1
8  2001    3   c1
9  2001    4    e
10 2001    5   d1
```

## Solution 2 fill NA values with dplyr left_join and mutate

Here I use dplyr `left_join` to join the new values. Use `full_join` if you want to also add combinations of time and var1 that were not present in the original panel. You will get columns `var2.x` and  `var2.y` columns and that's OK because it reflects the fact that there is an old and a new value. Then mutate to replace NA values by the new value.

```
result <- panel %>% 
    left_join(new.df, by = c("time", "var1")) %>% 
    mutate(var2 = ifelse(is.na(var2.x),var2.y,var2.x))
```

Then if you want to keep only the columns of interest

```
result <- result %>% select(time, var1, var2)
```

What do you plan to do if a new value replaces an existing value?
The code above will keep the old value.

Comment: It work but I need to control for the factors inside the ifelse function. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "factors"?  There are no factors in Akrun's answer. The method is different, I didn't know about  the nice `coalesce` function. But the result data frame is the same as Akrun's answer. I guess you may need to convert your var2 columns to character variables as Akrun has done by adding this line `mutate_each(funs(as.character), var2.x:var2.y) %>%` before the `mutate` line. But if you don't include factors in the first place, by creating character variables only, see `?data_frame` then this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply (assuming that all values in new.df map to a corresponding NA value in your Panel):

```
ind <- which(paste0(panel[,1],panel[,2]) %in% paste0(new.df[,1],new.df[,2]))
panel[ind,3] = new.df[,3]
```