# R Data.Table: In-memory left join multiple columns from left and right side

Tags: r, data.table, left-join

I want to merge two data tables on multiple columns using data table.

```
## The two tables
A <- data.table(a = 1:4, b = 12:15, c = 10:13)
   a  b  c
1: 1 12 10
2: 2 13 11
3: 3 14 12
4: 4 15 13

B <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 12:14, d = 10:12, e = 10:12)
   a  b  d  e
1: 1 12 10 10
2: 2 13 11 11
3: 3 14 12 12
```

I would like to get this result:

```
A <- merge(A, B, by = c('a', 'b'), all.x = T)
   a  b  c  d  e
1: 1 12 10 10 10
2: 2 13 11 11 11
3: 3 14 12 12 12
4: 4 15 13 NA NA
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598139/left-join-table-using-data-table/34600831#34600831) showed that data table can edit the A data frame in-memory, so it's more efficient when using large data sets. The code suggested is

```
A[B, bb:=i.b, on='a']
```

How can I alter this code so the A data frame is merged in-memory, and the result will be the same as above?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439976/update-a-subset-of-dataframe-rows-and-columns-from-another-dataframe/41440339#41440339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we meant to do a `join`.  Here the `i.d` or `i.e` is not needed as the columns are unique in the 'B'

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(B), names(A)) 
A[B, (nm1) :=  mget(nm1), on = .(a, b)]
A
#   a  b  c  d  e
#1: 1 12 10 10 10
#2: 2 13 11 11 11
#3: 3 14 12 12 12
#4: 4 15 13 NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Because I use two data sets with many more columns, is it possible to make this more flexible ? for example using setdiff(names(B), names(A)) in the j section of data table?